# TypeScript - how to create dict type that takes different functions as a value

Tags: typescript

```
export enum SomeKeys {
  FIRST_KEY = 'FIRST_KEY',
  SECOND_KEY = 'SECOND_KEY',
}

export const DICT: {
  [key in SomeKeys]: {
    title: string;
    greeter: () => {};
  };
} = {
  [SomeKeys.FIRST_KEY]: {
    title: 'first key title',
    greeter: (name: string) => ({ name }),
  },
  [SomeKeys.SECOND_KEY]: {
    title: 'second key title',
    greeter: (name: string, age: number) => ({
      name,
      age,
    }),
  },
};
```

Is it possible to create such a dictionary with strongly typed "greeter" function?

So I'd like to use those values as:

```
const { title, greeter } = DICT[SomeKeys.FIRST_KEY];
const { name } = greeter('Adam');
```

I hope it's clear enough to understand what's my problem

Comment: If you delete the explicit typing of `DICT`, [it seems to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMoVcA0sATwGc4BvAKDjgDEBJAJQwBUB9XAUQE04BeOAcjqNWHTvwA0lTOwDCAeQByAETZdeAjLMUrRE8gF9y5UJFhwAxhERF4S2jKbqKVANpYc+YgDohzVZwBdAC4yKSoYAEsYABtgEP4AMwioGzgAa0I4SJjgPSoqAHMoYGAYYCgQgApEAEMcEJsoCMQCgEpeAD44StI4Wpw4fVbJKn0RuDdsPEIiL015ZX9g0PysqNj4omBLRAATdMzs2Lz8opKyiu7+uLhG5oLxOBqCm5RUACNy9p4unrD867jVbPYBAwbDKRjAwAbiMO1SvSOoLgZ1K5UG6jsDkmHhmPgYflEAVh8PgvWuGL4qIulX4AEFdnV+K1YUA). Did you add the explicit typing for polymorphism, or just to check the dict entries for typos?

Comment: Yeah to check for typos, but I'll go without explicit typing I guess, as you mentioned - it works.

Comment: Does `SomeKeys.FIRST_KEY` some how connected with `greeter` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your explicit typing, TypeScript is taking your word for it that `DICT` has homogeneous keys of the type you specify; it erases the type information that you'd otherwise get from the constant dictionary. If you delete the typing, it works.

```
export const DICT /* typing removed */ = {
  [SomeKeys.FIRST_KEY]: {
    title: 'first key title',
    greeter: (name: string) => ({ name }),
  },
  [SomeKeys.SECOND_KEY]: {
    title: 'second key title',
    greeter: (name: string, age: number) => ({
      name,
      age,
    }),
  },
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMoVcA0sATwGc4BvAKDjgDEBJAJQwBUB9XAUQE04BeOAcjqNWHTvwA0lTOwDCAeQByAETZdeAjLMUrRE8gF9y5UJFhwAxhERF4S2jKbqKVANpYc+YgDohzVZwBdAC4yKSoYAEsYABtgEP4AMwioGzgAa0I4SJjgPSoqAHMoYGAYYCgQgApEAEMcEJsoCMQCgEpeAD44StI4Wpw4fVbJKn0RuDdsPEIiL015ZX9g0PysqNj4omBLRAATdMzs2Lz8opKyiu7+uLhG5oLxOBqCm5RUACNy9p4unrD867jVbPYBAwbDKRjAwAbiMO1SvSOoLgZ1K5UG6jsDkmHhmPgYflEAVh8PgvWuGL4qIulX4AEFdnV+K1YUA)

You can do slightly better with a helper function, which will check the completeness of SomeKeys and will throw if you don't correctly specify the expected fields:

```
type ExpectedKeyType = {
  [key in SomeKeys]: {
    title: string;
    greeter: unknown;
  }
};

function checkKeys<T extends ExpectedKeyType>(t: T) {
  return t;
}

export const DICT = checkKeys({
  /* snip, same as above */
  [SomeKeys.THIRD_KEY]: {
    title: 'third key title',
    greeter: (age: number) => ({ age }),
  },
});

const { title, greeter } = DICT[SomeKeys.THIRD_KEY];
const { age } = greeter(42);

// If you diverge from the value, it won't compile.
export const DICT_WITH_TYPO = checkKeys({
  /* snip */
  [SomeKeys.THIRD_KEY]: {
    title: 'third key title',
    egregiousTypo: (age: number) => ({ age }), // error here
  },
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMoVcA0sATwGc4BvAKDjgDEBJAJQwBUB9XAUQE04BeOAcjqNWHTvwA0lTOwDCAeQByAETZdeAjLMUrREqUwASDHWr79Dx1WMkBfcuRgEwwOO3DAAxjGAATfASYnFz4KKgBtAGtCOABLRExsPEIiAF0ALjIpKhgYmAAbYAyiGCg4gHMAbiy4MqhgYG8oDORECMQIAHdEKqo7GyryADMWrxiIeI8AC08I-yIAHiYEEG9EHxI3Zy9ff0DnAD4AChgMpgBKTKo6mGQoeJgqu3JQSFg4D3HiuCVaGSW+KYzOaHUJwMJYHBzAB0QmYVnSlyocBy+UKAkGMSgXyiBGRuQKeiRNTqDWATTgh0QAEMcEUSuULjx9hTSHBqTg4DYzpJejywRCksQoZp5Mp4RlQdl8Wj+ERPOMfHAcXjUYSkbV6o0MpSaWjiqVEGVxHAqWU0ShUAAjMmM5kg6pUdnAPlE03O6pcvk2PngxLQiz0EycBGSlUFDL8GCTTGK5Uogku4masnat0ZC3WqC2lkms2c7lSb3kLkDD6IL6s+POpOkqCc9Q-P6+yHJKEBoMpKpliu5lw2dQa2uHAAsACYzgMAPSTuC0QZwAgQZBwHwxABuZLzgyg2GR0zga6peWQ1dycA640j72wYBiBShz3A0Hg3fgjdYAHVaIYWExOAAFOR1EBDxZmSe1wgFaFYRELgQ2qKsIwxLF4DjaU1SoQctQpJ06QNMpsxBNldXzL0fSg1sRW0cVESlVEIzlMtY2iKsMJrbCdVpOB9XKY00zZNBM0I0NHV1RMqDdRNPULci-VbdsaNDRCBCjGMlRY9DE2ADUyjGZAiD2CBUzNdNBJtXg7VZN1SJk4sJ3IIA)